# Programa en C no me respeta las condiciones establecidas

Tags: c

soy alumno de primer semestre en programación y debo hacer un código en el cual se cumplan las siguientes condiciones:  debe ser mujer, debe tener una edad entre 18 y 30 años, debe
tener por lo menos 3 años laborando en la empresa y además debe contar con todas sus vacunas y
haber pasado el examen general de sangre. Si se cumplen las condiciones se imprime que es apto para una prestacion.

Les comparto mi código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int edad,experiencia;
   
   char sexo,vacunas,examen,F,M,S,N,NA,A;
   
printf("Capture su sexo F-Femenino, M-Masculino \n");
    scanf(" %c",&sexo);
printf("Capture su edad \n");
    scanf("%d",&edad);
printf("Capture sus años laborando en la empresa \n");
    scanf("%d",&experiencia);
printf("¿Cuenta con todas sus vacunas? S-SI N-NO \n");
    scanf(" %c",&vacunas);
printf("Resultado general del examen de sangre A-Apta NA-NO APTA \n");
    scanf(" %c",&examen);

if(sexo==F&&edad>=18&&edad<=30&&experiencia>=3&&vacunas==S&&examen==A){
    printf("Felicidades, usted califica para la prestacion");
    }
    else{
    printf("Lo lamentamos, usted no aplica para la prestacion");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

El problema es que siempre me imprime que no aplica para la prestacion aunque las condiciones si se cumplan. Gracias.

Comment: Nececitas las comillas por 'F', 'S', 'A', etcetera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error se produce porque al momento de tomar una instrucción `sexo == F` hace referencia a una variable llamada *F* que aunque fue declarada, nunca se le asignó un valor, ejm `F = 'F';`.

Este tipo de errores es muy comunes al empezar a programar pero es importante tener en cuenta los tipos de datos que existen y saber diferenciar las variables o atributos de las cadenas de caracteres.

En conclusión el codigo debería quedar asi:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int edad,experiencia;

   char sexo,vacunas,examen;

    printf("Capture su sexo F-Femenino, M-Masculino \n");
    scanf(" %c",&sexo);
    printf("Capture su edad \n");
    scanf("%d",&edad);
    printf("Capture sus años laborando en la empresa \n");
    scanf("%d",&experiencia);
    printf("¿Cuenta con todas sus vacunas? S-SI N-NO \n");
    scanf(" %c",&vacunas);
    printf("Resultado general del examen de sangre A-Apta NA-NO APTA \n");
    scanf(" %c",&examen);

    if(sexo=='F' && edad >= 18 && edad <= 30 && experiencia >= 3 && vacunas == 'S' && examen == 'A'){
        printf("Felicidades, usted califica para la prestacion");
    }
    else{
        printf("Lo lamentamos, usted no aplica para la prestacion");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

El código que usted tiene podría funcionar si se asignan los valores a las variables así

```
F = 'F';
S = 'S';
A = 'A';
```

Pero pues no tendría mucho sentido y sería una mala practica de programación.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciono como me dijiste